# Check if contract already deployed in Brownie

Tags: contract-deployment, python, brownie, smart-contract

im writing a script in **python and brownie** to deploy my smart contract to a testnet but i want to set an if statement for not deploying the smart contract if its already deployed .
I know that deployed contracts are stored in the `build/deployments/map.json` file but how can i check that the contract is already in this json file (i.e. contract already deployed) or there is a keyword in brownie syntax to check this ? Help please .

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Project.load() method to try to load the contract from the build/deployments/map.json file. If the contract is not found in the file, an error will be raised.